# Vim Autocomplete Single Quotes

Tags: vim

In my .vimrc, I'm trying to do autocomplete `"` to `""`. I can't seem to escape these properly with `\"\"`.

```
inoremap \" \"\"<Esc>i
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key mappings aren't interpreted as VimScript expressions unless you use the special `<expr>` keyword; it's just literal characters. Try typing `\"` and see what your mapping does ;-)

So there is no need to escape the `"` to prevent it from being interperted as a quote characters. This will just work:

```
:inoremap " ""<Esc>i
```

Comment: Interesting - it works when I do it when I'm in vim, but if I put it in my `~/.vimrc` it replaces `"` with `1`

Comment: Ah it was from another command that was not working - it works now! :)

Comment: With recent version of vim, prefer `<c-g>U<left>`, it'll offer redo. (Otherwise, I also prefer `<left>` to `<esc>i`)